# Why rotating a function in this paper uses $R^{-1}$ and not $R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, spherical-harmonics

If you look at Eq. 1 of this (paper)[http://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10130], it states that

"*we introduce the rotation operator $L_R$ that takes a function $f$ and produces a rotated function $L_Rf$ by composing $f$ with the rotation $R^{−1}$:
$$
[L_Rf](x) = f(R^{−1}x).
$$
Due to the inverse on $R$, we have $L_{RR′} = L_RL_R′$.*"

1. It seems something trivial, but I cant get my head around it that if $L_R$ rotates the function, then should not $[L_Rf](x) = f(Rx)$, i.e. rotated function being equivalent to function on rotated input? (as main thrust of paper is towards equivariance.)
2. Why does $R^{-1}$ help in meeting the condition $L_{RR′} = L_RL_R′$ and not $R$ itself?

Comment: I believe if you use $R$ in the definition of $L_R$, then you would have $$L_{RR'} = L_{R'}L_R.$$

Comment: It's the same reason that if we want to shift $f(x)$ by a positive amount, we write $f(x - a)$ and not $f(x + a)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah! Of course. Somehow I never thought of that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$L_RL_{R'}(f)(x)=L_Rf(R'^{-1}x)$$$$=f(R'^{-1}R^{-1}x)=f((RR')^{-1}x)$$$$=L_{RR'}(f)(x)$$
The important fact is that $(RR')^{-1}=R'^{-1}R^{-1}$.